# Error in connecting 2 modbus slave pymodbus

Tags: python, python-3.x, modbus, pymodbus, pymodbus3

I am working on pymodbus.
Trying to read the data from multiple units (multiple slaves) it gives me data but when the 1 of the slaves did not respond or is off the other slaves also shows the error after some time.
please help.
Thank you

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusIOException
from pymodbus.exceptions import ConnectionException

def length(x):
    client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=2, stopbits = 1, bytesize = 8,  parity='N', baudrate = 9600)
    client.connect()
    rr = client.read_holding_registers(address=1, count=4, unit=x);
    decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(rr.registers, Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big);
    a=str(decoder.decode_32bit_float());
    c = int (float(a))
    client.close()
    print("length",c)
    client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=2, stopbits = 1, bytesize = 8,  parity='N', baudrate = 9600)
    client.connect()
    rr = client.read_holding_registers(address=7, count=4, unit=x);
    decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(rr.registers, Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big);
    b=str(decoder.decode_32bit_float());
    d = int (float(b))
    client.close()
    print("speed",d)
    print(x)
    return c,d
```

Comment: Please put on the full trace of your error

Comment: after running some time the code shows error  'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'  if one of the connected slave is off

Comment: I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52990404/3702377), I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: `count=4` reading and `decode_32bit_float()` are contradicted together, because you read 4regs, and each register in Modbus is a *Word Type*, each word is *2Byte*, Thus you read *8Byte*, So you read *64bit* that you need  decode it with `decode_64bit_float()`.

Comment: I had solve the above issue. The actual problem was because of the thread.

Comment: So you can put on your answer to below your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've improved your code with the `.isError()` method in pymodbus as the following:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder

def error_checker(instance):
    if not instance.isError():
        '''.isError() implemented in pymodbus 1.4.0 and above.'''
        decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(
            instance.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big
        )
        return decoder.decode_32bit_float()
    else:
        # Error handling.
        return None

def length(x):
    client = ModbusClient(
        method='rtu',
        port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
        timeout=2, stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=9600
    )
    try:
        client.connect()
        rr = client.read_holding_registers(address=1, count=4, unit=x)
        c = error_checker(rr)
        print("length: ", c)
        rr = client.read_holding_registers(address=7, count=4, unit=x)
        d = error_checker(rr)
        print("speed: ", d)
        return c, d
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
    finally:
        client.close()
```